# ProcessExit vs DomainUnload

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm working on a bug where code is not always being executed before an application shuts down. The code was in a handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload event.

I found a post by someone with the same problem who received this advice

"By the time the DomainUnload event happens for your default app domain, your
code has stopped executing. You can probably do what you need to with the
ProcessExit event on the default AppDomain."

This worked for me but I would like to know why. I haven't been able to find much on either of these events or on the differences between them. I'm also wondering if I need to subscribe to both or is the ProcessExit sufficient.

EDIT:

I wanted to add more information to make this a little more useful.

I left out that new threads were being created in their own AppDomain. Since I wanted this code to run not only when the parent process was done but also when each thread finished I needed to subscribe to the DomainUnload event to handle when each thread finished and also the ProcessExit event to catch when the parent process finished.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ProcessExit` should be sufficient.

The `DomainUnload` event is designed to be handled by other AppDomains, not the `AppDomain` being unloaded. As a result, if the handler is attached in the domain being unloaded, it might not run. The `ProcessExit` event is designed to run when the process is *going to* exit.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload(v=vs.110).aspx) says `AppDomain.DomainUnload` Event "Occurs when an AppDomain is about to be unloaded." and is meant to be used by the `AppDomain` being unloaded.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari: It seems it's not so: `be reminded that after the DomainUnload event is fired, you will never see a ProcessExit event because your AppDomain is already gone` - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16164/Managed-Application-Shutdown

Comment: Having multiple AppDomains (and thus the AppDomain.DomainUnload event) was removed with .Net core. AppDomain.DomainUnload will never be triggered. 
See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0024